# How can I extract conditional data using json extractor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Following is the json response that I am getting for one request.

```
"JobStages": [
            {
                "JobStageName": "Screening Phase",
                "JobStageID": 1,
                "Message": "",
                "JobStageIsRequired": true,
                "JobStageIsAnyRequired": false,
                "JobStageActivities": [
                    {
                        "ActivityName": "Phone Call",
                        "ActivityIsRequired": false,
                        "ActivityID": 1,
                        "IsActivityRejected": false
                    },
```

How can I extract value of ActivityIsRequired for Activity Phone Call using json extractor in Jmeter?
For example I want to extract value of `ActivityIsRequired` for `ActivityName` of `JobStageID 1`.

I am trying with this `$..JobStages..JobStageActivities..[?(@.ActivityName == "Phone Call" &amp;&amp; @.JobStageID == 1)].ActivityIsRequired`

but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like:

```
$.JobStages[?(@.JobStageID == 1)].JobStageActivities.[?(@.ActivityName == 'Phone Call')].ActivityIsRequired
```

should do the trick for you.

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath - Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)